# Using jQuery to target tag by style attribute and change it to another tag with a class

Tags: jquery, html

Here the is code that I have:

```
<script> 
  $('span style=“text-decoration:underline;"').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<h3 class=“classSAmple”/>', {
      html: $(this).html()
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

Edited, added the \": 
I need to target the whole span string.

```
<script>
$("span style=\"text-decoration:underline;\"").replaceWith(function () {
    return $("<h3 class=\"classSAmple\"/>", {
        html: $(this).html()
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: And the problem you're having with that code is...? We'll also need a [mcve]. When does that code execute, in the head, at the end of the page, or in a ready handler?

Comment: @j08691 it executes at the end of the page. The problem is that the span is not changed to h3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly the `“` character is invalid JS. You need to use the `"` double quote character instead.

Secondly selecting an element by its inline style is a *really* bad idea. If you have absolutely no other choice (which would be selecting by `class`, `id`, or even just a hierarchical selector) then you could use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) or `filter()`. The latter is far more robust.

Thirdly, note that the exact CSS property you're checking against in this case is `text-decoration-line`, not just `text-decoration` as that's a shorthand for several other rules.

Lastly, when you create the new `h3` element, if you're going to provide a property list, you need to include *all* properties in there. You cannot have the class in the element string, then other properties within the object.

With all that said, try this:

```js
var $span = $('span').filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('text-decoration-line') === 'underline';
}).replaceWith(function() {
  return $('<h3 />', {
    'class': 'classSample',
    'html': $(this).html()
  });
});
```

```css
h3.classSample { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Unaffected</span>
<span style="text-decoration: underline">This is now an h3...</span>
<span>Unaffected</span>
```